# willTransitionToState Not getting called (UITableview)

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to show and hide a subview when the UITableview is in editing mode *and* while it's showing the delete button (the entire editing and deleting process, not just editing), then make it disappear when it goes back into *normal* mode.

I'm really close to getting it the way I want, but every time you click on a "delete" button in the cell, it makes my view disappear, when I don't want it to disappear until the user exits edit mode completely.

I'm trying to use the delegate method `- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state` but I'm getting an error when I call `super`:

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state {

    [super willTransitionToState:state];

    if ((state & UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask)) {
        clear.alpha = 1.0;
    }
}
```

The error is a common one, but I can't seem to find a solution:

> No visible @interface for 'UITableViewController' declares the
>   selector 'willTransitionToState:'

I don't get the error if I don't call super, but the method never gets called either.

I've also tried using `setEditing`, but the view that I want to stay visible during the entire editing/deleting process disappears when the delete button is tapped, deleting the cell, but still in editing mode

Comment: I was setting the alpha property of my view in 'numberOfRowsInSection, causing the disappearance problem, but I still don't know why willTransitionToState isn't getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call that method (willTransitionToState:) in your custom tableview **cell**. it isn't a method that is recognized in a UITableViewController class. if you call willTransitionToState: in the .m file if your custom tableview cell class, it should work. Just make sure that cell class has the ivar 'clear' defined (which you seem to have, based on the code you provided). Also check out the layoutSubviews method if you'd like to do things like prevent the cells from indenting content while editing.

Answer (score 1):

`willTransitionToState` is a method on `UITableViewCell` not on `UITableViewController`.